# Asymptotic stability of prime divisors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Suppose $I$ is an ideal in a formally equidimensional local ring $R.$ Let $A(I)$ and $\overline A(I)$ denote Ass$R/I^n$ and Ass$R/\overline{I^n}$ for all large $n$ respectively.

*My question is*

**What are the sufficient conditions for  $A(I)=\overline A(I)?$**

I know that if $I$ is edge ideal then the above equality holds.